# Script to capture requested response from submitted form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The code below should capture the response from a submitted form and display it in a `<div>` in my jsp page, but this isn't happening:

```
<script>
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

          // Stop form from submitting normally
          event.preventDefault();

          // Get some values from elements on the page:
          var $form = $( this ),
            url = $form.attr( "action" );

          // Send the data using post
          var posting = $.post( url );

          // Put the results in a div
          posting.done(function( data ) {
            var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
            $( "#result" ).append( content );
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Considering that my form is:

```
<form method="post" action="cad_evento.html" id="target">
        <p><input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" size=20 maxlength=40> </p>

        <p><input type="text" name="descricao" placeholder="Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o" size=30 maxlength=100> </p>

        <h3>Periodo da Data</h3>
        <p>inicio: <input name="data_inicial" placeholder="DD-MM-AAAA" pattern="\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}" /> </p>
        <p>final: <input name="data_final" placeholder="DD-MM-AAAA" pattern="\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}" /> </p>

        <h3>Periodo do Hor&aacute;rio</h3>
        <p>inicio: <input name="hora_inicial" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" pattern="\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}" /> </p>
        <p>final: <input name="hora_final" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" pattern="\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}" /> </p>

        <p><input type="text" name="duracao" placeholder="dura&ccedil;&atilde;o" size=20 maxlength=2> Minutos </p>

        <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button></p>
    </form>
```

Someone can see any error preventing the script to do correctly what it supposed to do?

Comment: You know you're not sending anything with that $.post ?

Comment: I'm using a snippet of code from jquery documentaton (this link: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ -> last example of the page),supposing it's right. Do you can identify any error caused by my changes?

Comment: Try sending the form? `var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );`

Comment: yes, seems like it's working partially. the output in browser console indicate the page cad_evento.html is reached, but none text is displayed in the <div> identified by id "result".

Comment: Then try `var content = $('<div />', {html : data}).find( "#content" );` and see if that works

Comment: Ok, now it's working. I just remove the line **var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );** and replace the other by **$( "#result" ).empty().append( data );**. probably the first one depends from format of the response.